# How to limit number of characters typed in a textbox in MFC?

Tags: mfc, editcontrol

I have 2 questions...my 1st question is how do I limit the number of character typed in a textbox in MFC..say if I want the user to type only 4 characters..the text box should take only 4 character.And my 2nd question is when it exceeds the character limit it should jump to the next textbox/tab control.I tried using the following code..but it seem to not work in my case...Please help me if you know any alternatives...

CEdit::SetLimitText(4);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

handle the EN_CHANGE message (OnEnChange). In that handler, find the number of chars the textbox has. If it's more than 4, remove the last ones. If it's four, use `NextDlgCtrl()` to tab to the next control or use `SetFocus()` to set the focus to a specific control.

Comment: tnax for ur quick reply stefan...thats a good idea..actually I tried that but it didnt work somehow..but let me double check that again one more time and I also went through another article and thought of using ON_EN_MAXTTEXT..will try that real quick and will let u Know friend..

Comment: Oh!stevan..I tried that now its working gr8..its simple but sumtime we tend to make things  complicated..but anyways..I really appreciate ur help.